# TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation

Tags: tfs, release, release-management, tfs-2015, tfs-security

I am created build and deploying those using TFS 2015. Everything was proper but from last two weeks the Build is being created successfully but the Release part is throwing error

> TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to
>   complete the operation:[*****]\Project Collection Service Accounts.
>   The following permission is needed to perform this operation:View
>   Project-level Information

So I verified the team project-> security settings. View Project-level Information is set to Allowed for all the groups except Project valid user. All the other groups are member of Project valid user so I do not think it should be a issue.

Can somebody help me out and give a proper solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add "Project Collection Service Accounts" as member of "Release Administrators" group.

Comment: This did not help for me.

Comment: What did help for me was to run `az account clear && az login`, because apparently I had an old account cached or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was in visual studio so after opening visual studio installer and selecting repair option the issue disappeared.

Comment: A short answer is welcome, however it won't provide much value to the latter users who are trying to understand what's going on behind the problem. Please spare some time to explain what's the real issue to cause the problem and how to solve. Thank you ~

Comment: I don't know the root cause of the issue, but what i mentioned fixed the issue for me so i shared how it was fixed .

Answer (score 0):

When you add accounts of users directly to a TFS group or through a Windows group, they are automatically added to one of the valid user groups.

TFS uses a least-permissive model for security permissions. What that means is that if a user belongs to two groups and the same permission is assigned Allow for one group and Deny for another group, Deny takes precedence over Allow.

So, if View Project-level Information is set to Allow in one group, but set Deny in Project valid user group, Deny takes precedence over Allow. You need to check the group permission that the account belongs to, and make sure every group has the proper permission.

Comment: All the group had proper permissions. The issue got resolved by adding "Project Collection Service Accounts" as member of "Release Administrators" group.

Answer (score 0):

If you imported the definition in from another TFS/DevOps, it is possible that there is a unique identifier in the template export that needs to be changed or cleared out.